# webpack share data between custom loader and plugin

Tags: webpack

#### Explanation

I'm developing a webpack custom loader, that is in charge of parsing the javascript and search for certain text using regex.

I need to have a way to collect the data between each parsed file and finally pass that data to a related plugin, so that the plugin can make the appropriate action with that data.

#### My failed strategy

I can use a module to share data between loader calls, but this data is not available in the plugins.

#### Suggestions ?

I've been looking at the way the extract-text-plugin does it, since it has a loader and a plugin, but looking at their source code, the way they declare the module is strange to me and I can't really grasp their strategy.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6):

Using a shared module is a viable option, I created a loader/plugin combo that creates an SVG sprite from svgs imported through the loader, here is the repository: https://github.com/crystal-ball/svg-symbol-sprite-loader

Here is how I setup the process:

1. I export a singleton as the [`sprite-store`](https://github.com/crystal-ball/svg-symbol-sprite-loader/blob/master/src/sprite-store.js)
2. The [`loader`](https://github.com/crystal-ball/svg-symbol-sprite-loader/blob/master/src/loader.js) requires the sprite store and adds any imported SVG to the store.
3. In the additional assets hook the [`plugin`](https://github.com/crystal-ball/svg-symbol-sprite-loader/blob/master/src/plugin.js) reads all of the collected data from the sprite store.

Comment: Great1 what's the official way?