# Communication between Webpack loader and plugin

Tags: webpack

I wrote my own Webpack loader that parses a certain type of files and I would like to pass some metadata back to the Webpack compiler and specifically back to the `html-webpack-plugin` so It can render those to the template.

I've been looking through Webpack documentation and maybe writing a plugin can help with that, but I don't see any obvious way to do it.

What's the right approach?

Comment: Found a similar question with a potential answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308248/webpack-share-data-between-custom-loader-and-plugin?rq=1